# Left JOIN on DATE field not working in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, left-join

This is an Order Management System scenario.

I have a `[SalesHistory]` Table with following fields:
    **ItemMasterID** `varchar(60)`
    **Qty** `int`
    **OrderDate** `DateTime`
(Omitted non relevant fields)

Executing following query on `SalesHistory`:

```
select Cast(OrderDate as Date) 'OrderDate',Sum(Qty) 'Qty'  from SalesHistory 
where itemmasterid= '001FCB08-B72E-4D1A-91D6-C3D8A8CF7008' 
Group by ItemMasterId ,Cast(OrderDate as DAte)
order by OrderDate desc
```

I get the following results (As expected)
[image]

As you can see, for the month of `04` there are only 4 records.
What I expect is that all the days of a month be displayed on the left side (Date column) with zeros on the right side (Qty column) if there is no record for that particular date

---

*Here is what I tried:*

I created a table `[Date_Ref]` with field:
    **Day** `DateTime`

Then I filled it up with all days of month `04` using the following procedure:

```
declare @SD Date = convert(Date,'04/01/2017',101)
declare @ED Date = convert(Date,'04/30/2017',101)
declare @DatePeriod Date = @SD
while (@DatePeriod <= @ED)
begin
    insert into Date_Ref (Day) values (@DatePeriod)
    set @DatePeriod = DATEADD(DD, 1,@DatePeriod)
end
```

Now the `Date_Ref` table is filled with expected records:

```
select Day 'Date' from Date_Ref
```

[image]

---

I tried using `LEFT JOIN` on this and `SalesHistory` table expecting to get the result I mentioned above:

```
select Cast(d.Day as Date) 'Date',ISNULL (s.Qty,0) 'Qty' 
from date_Ref as d 
left join 
SalesHistory as s on Cast(s.OrderDate as date) = cast(d.Date_Period as date) 
where 
s.itemmasterid = '001FCB08-B72E-4D1A-91D6-C3D8A8CF7008'
```

and I got his result:
[image]

---

Clearly this is not what I EXPECTED.!! I excepected something like:

```
+-------------+----+
| Date        | Qty|
+-------------+----+
| 2017-04-01  |   0|
| 2017-04-02  |   0|
| 2017-04-03  |   0|
| 2017-04-04  |   0|
| 2017-04-05  |   0|
| 2017-04-06  |   0|
| 2017-04-07  |   0|
| 2017-04-08  |   0|
| 2017-04-09  |   0|
| 2017-04-10  |   1|
| 2017-04-11  |   1|
....
....
```

---

Why is the `LEFT JOIN` behaving like an `INNER JOIN`? Or is this how SQL returns when you join on `DateTime` field?

**Note**:
I also tried removing the `Cast`.
I also tried all the joins `LEFT` `RIGHT` `OUTER` `INNER`.
I also tried switching positions of `SalesHistory` and `Date_Ref` tables in the query.

Is it that I am doing something wrong? Or is there another approach to this?

Thankyou

*Sorry for the lengthy question!! I just had to describe the exact steps what I did*

Comment: You are left joining SalesHistory as s  but you aso have a where condition on the table. When you left join, this might be null (=no data for this record) but by applying the condition, you eliminate all rows that do not ahve a match. This means you need to allow a null value in the where condition (e.g. where s.itemmasterid is null or s.itemmasterid = '001FCB08-B72E-4D1A-91D6-C3D8A8CF7008') or completely remove this part

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
where s.itemmasterid = '001FCB08-B72E-4D1A-91D6-C3D8A8CF7008'
```

turns your join into an inner join. In an outer-joined record `s.itemmasterid` is null, so the condition is not matched and you dismiss the row.

Conditions on outer-joined tables belong in the `ON` clause.

```
select Cast(d.Day as Date) 'Date', ISNULL (s.Qty,0) 'Qty' 
from date_Ref as d 
left join SalesHistory as s on cast(s.OrderDate as date) = cast(d.Date_Period as date)
                            and s.itemmasterid = '001FCB08-B72E-4D1A-91D6-C3D8A8CF7008'
```

Comment: That was perfect! Thankyou for your time

Comment: I have spent hours troubleshooting a scenario like this and had no idea that WHERE conditions change the join type. I [re]read several tutorials online and questions on SO and none mentioned this. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

Condition `s.itemmasterid = '001FCB08-B72E-4D1A-91D6-C3D8A8CF7008'` shoult belongs to `left join`:

```
select Cast(d.Day as Date) 'Date',ISNULL (s.Qty,0) 'Qty' 
from date_Ref as d 
left join SalesHistory as s on 
    Cast(s.OrderDate as date) = cast(d.Date_Period as date) 
    and s.itemmasterid = '001FCB08-B72E-4D1A-91D6-C3D8A8CF7008'
```

Comment: Thankyou for your time!!.. Worked exactly as expected